# Why does python fail to catch my "ResourceDoesNotExist" error from canvasapi?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

My program is supposed to access the Canvas API. It does this using an access token. I need to catch an exception that occurs when an invalid token is used and the API cannot find any resources associated with it. When testing my try/except statement, it fails to catch the "ResourceDoesNotExist" exception. This is the correct error type, and it is the error that I see when the program crashes.

```
try:
    self.canvas_api = Canvas(API_URL, API_TOKEN)
    self.user_name = self.canvas_api.get_current_user().name
    self.user_uid = self.canvas_api.get_current_user().id
except (CanvasException, exceptions.InvalidAccessToken, exceptions.ResourceDoesNotExist) as e:
    self.user_name = "Invalid Token"
    self.user_uid = e
    print(e)
```

[image]

I  tried adding a more general exception type such as "CanvasException", but this failed as well, letting the "ResourceDoesNotExist" exception through.